# Asp.net Core 1.1.2 OpenID connect cookies not being created on redirect, Set-Cookie header is added

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, openid-connect, setcookie

I am using ASP.NET core 1.1.2 with OpenIDConnect to connect to a Single Sign On server by IdentityServer.
    `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.1.2"`

Right now I am having a weird issue, that didn't happen until yesterday.

The initial cookies that should be created before being redirected to SSO server is not being created on browsers.

Using developer console on browsers, I can see the `Set-Cookie` header but cookies are not being stored.

```
   Content-Length: 0
   Date: Mon, 14 Jan 2019 18:50:10 GMT
   Location: http://mysso.com/connect/authorize?client_id=8111797110116117109&redirect_uri=http%3A%...ZD7cNnuWSmAoGyk2kERmR4hemQKsP2OKNbABYvybQCrdCMggrggDuY-5ZXnCTFf3oG11cR4Eh5N3Uarh99MD1nvJZrO4WsWDO73OQrEjh-zK3AceJzjfB2GH0gKKw-51SpcUWNgSTbQe517
   Server: Kestrel
   Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc.I3lU6aE3BFH_4uuJ6KlgbpFl6Dij_WC-nyhlbUfvAPI=N; expires=Mon, 14 Jan 2019 18:07:24 GMT; path=/; httponly
   Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8BWkCPQm5ElIof7iuryYpWDHYvyls6nYDr84XfQAIcLzg0ktLHIGOP7Tp_eqbvDOTdcQqnKIIogwMad9tWSy9v8BPnN8VUBucuz8qc9kv5Pkpe5aCg9oh6dgQD79a-w8Lc9haFm_tOEze1Wzna3XG7OzcGhw8kwyU5j3K_sK3Z7Y-u3cE_pey9DVbBzZkZStJXpoNjG_HWJHBjuqv7ADfCc91Oi83Ieuk7bBue8md1v2WqvSji3ziHkqyw9FKTV44Iw2Kg4o8Rf_3G-Q9ITNwr8=N; expires=Mon, 14 Jan 2019 18:07:24 GMT; path=/; httponly
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I checked if the cookies are being expired before creation but, they all have 10 min time left before expiry.

This issue is happening on all major browsers (edge, chrome, firefox), not just my pc but others too.

Configuration code

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                Authority = Configuration["SSOConfig:ServerUrl"],
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                SignInScheme = AuthenticationScheme.Cookies,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                ClientId = Configuration["SSOConfig:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = Configuration["SSOConfig:ClientSecret"],
                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                Scope = { "openid", "offline_access" },
                SaveTokens = false,
```

I tried adding cookies manually, and it is working.

`HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Test", "test");`

Comment: Cookies are domain specific. Are you perhaps adding cookies on one domain, and then trying to access from another?

Comment: the issue must have been `path=/sigin-oidc; secure` in cookies. But i don't know why it was problem untill now.

Comment: Brock Allen talks about `signin-oidc` on the Introduction to IdentityServer for ASP.NET Core video at MS Academy https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/introduction-to-identityserver-for-aspnet-core-17945 (also available on YouTube). They also talk about the challenges of having Identity Server on a different domain to the application, so cookies need to be managed more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Seems like, somehow the cookies set were expired cookies.

I had to upgrade the system to .net core 2.
*The difference I found between the two was on `set-cookie`. `path=/signin-oidc; secure`*

```
   Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2019 10:53:04 GMT
   Location: https://mysso.com/connect/authorize?client_id=8111797110243116117109&redirect_ur...
   Server: Kestrel
   Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc.Iy3pTZ-akQm6BzLMCdBPLz1CAGTJ70QgQtjkY9Kvg1Y=N; expires=Tue, 15 Jan 2019 11:08:04 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure; httponly
   Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8Oct5aw6xUJOnpJ_-0Ep-nSLfWIXgaEiH7y-0IN9tx61lNrxFhgAzLvLlBQfOfBBegyRJrEsIZFi00iuUt90cJ_bMQI_1XTVr0SiBCAJ9wqR2682VrYe2IbjIrFuB9d-Mmu-ztw-O2Htzd8Z36ndD8zPsgSCY_RD6JYVRe4MTfFBQbDZRxMQ3rgB_ulvSZmshD7vB4gvgcsbLyiY2wVuKzVGEKgJxgq23nxzkNKkL-vHm6w_41D_rZI5_V9hDsfrShFuTViZNttAes1fmA2jMTQ=N; expires=Tue, 15 Jan 2019 11:08:04 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure; httponly
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET``
```

Comment: Is your problem gone after updating to net core 2.0?